# How to implement change password modal form?

Tags: django, ajax, bootstrap-modal

EDIT 14/07/2021

Reading this blog post (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html) I understand how to prevent user logout (update_session_auth_hash(self.request, self.object) added to form_valid function) and I am very close to the solution using attempt #2

BUT

there still have "grey" screen after user pasword successfully changed and user have to click on screen to make it disappeared...

---

EDIT 14/07/2021

I quite closeto the solution following this tutorial https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2015/11/18/modal-django-forms-bootstrap-4/

Neverthless it is not working correctly.

attempt #1: get_success_url

I override get_success_url funtion of PasswordChangeView to redirectto index page and use SuccessMessageMixin to confirm password change. Password is correctly changed but somthig is going wrong with return (see capture below)

[image]

attemp #2: form_valid

I've tried another way overriding form_valid function that return JsonObject. Password is also changed but screen stay as modal was still opened. When I click on screen, "grey" diappeared but if I refresh page (F5) i am redirected to home page and I am disconnected without error... and message "Your password has been successfully changed" is displayed even if modal return error...

[image]

---

I have implemented authentification using Django django.contrib.auth and it work but I would like **change_password** to be displayed using modal form and Ajax.

And I do not manage to even display the form inside modal (with all validation stuff).

I have already use bootstrap modal to display information but not for form submission. As it did not call a change_password view that render change_password_form.html template, form is not available and I got an error `Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.`

How should I do this?

urls.py

```
class PasswordChangeView(SuccessMessageMixin, auth_views.PasswordChangeView): 
    <!-- attempt #1 -->    
    success_message = "Your password have been changed successfully."
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('export:index')
    
    <!-- attempt #2 -->
    # def form_valid(self, form):
    #     self.object = form.save()
    #     update_session_auth_hash(self.request, self.object) # prevent user’s auth session to be invalidated and user have to log in again   
    #     return JsonResponse ({'data': 'success'},status = 200)

app_name = 'registration'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('change_password/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    ...
]
```

password_change_form.html (modified)

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
<div id = "password_change" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'registration:password_change' %}" method="post" id="password_change" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class='card' style="border-top-width: 0px;border-left-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;">
                <div style="background-color:#326690;padding:5px 5px 5px 16px;color:white;font-weight:bold;border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;">Change password</div>
                <form method="post" class="form-signin">
                    <div class='card-body' style="padding-bottom:0px">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" placeholder="None" size="medium" label_class="form-label col-md-3" %}
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin:1px">
                    <div class='card-body' style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                        <div>           
                            <button type="submit" class="btn block" style="float:right;background-color:#326690;color:white;min-width:110px;">{% trans 'Confirm' %}</button>
                            <!--<a href="{% url 'export:index' %}" class="btn btn-light border" style="float:right;color:#326690;min-width:110px;margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% trans 'Cancel' %}</a> -->                 
                            <span data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light border" style="float:right;color:#326690;min-width:110px;margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% trans 'Cancel' %}</span>              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var form_options = { target: '#modal', success: function(response) {
        console.log('response',response);
        //obj = JSON.parse(response);
        $("#password_change_confirm").append('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span>Your password has been changed successfully.</span></div>');
    } };
    $('#password_change').ajaxForm(form_options);

</script>
```

base.html (modified)

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'registration:password_change' %}"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {% trans 'Change password' %}</a>

<div class="modal" id="modal"></div>
```

index.html (added)

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
...
    <!-- message for change password in authentification module -->
    <div id="password_change_confirm" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;"></div>

    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
      <div id = 'msg' class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert" >
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ message }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} 
    <!-- end message for change password in authentification module -->
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally find a 'hack' solution that works, do know if it is the better way but it's works:

base.html

```
<!-- https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2015/11/18/modal-django-forms-bootstrap-4/ -->
<div class="modal" id="modal" style="margin-top:150px;"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-qlmct0AOBiA2VPZkMY3+2WqkHtIQ9lSdAsAn5RUJD/3vA5MKDgSGcdmIv4ycVxyn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var modal = $(this)
          $.ajax({
              url: "{% url 'registration:password_change' %}",
              context: document.body
          }).done(function(response) {
              modal.html(response);
          });
      })
)};
```

registration/views.py

```
class PasswordChangeView(auth_views.PasswordChangeView): 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(self.request, self.object) # prevent user’s auth session to be invalidated and user have to log in again 
        return JsonResponse ({'data': form.is_valid()},status = 200)
```

registration/urls.py

```
app_name = 'registration'
urlpatterns = [path('change_password/', PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),]
```

registration/template/registration/password_change_form.html

```
<!-- https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2015/11/18/modal-django-forms-bootstrap-4/ -->
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
<div id = "password_change" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'registration:password_change' %}" method="post" id="password_change" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class='card' style="border-top-width: 0px;border-left-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;">
                <div style="background-color:#326690;padding:5px 5px 5px 16px;color:white;font-weight:bold;border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;">Change password</div>
                <form method="post" class="form-signin">
                    <div class='card-body' style="padding-bottom:0px">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" placeholder="None" size="medium" label_class="form-label col-md-3" %}
                    </div>
                    <hr style="margin:1px">
                    <div class='card-body' style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                        <div>           
                            <button type="submit" class="btn block" style="float:right;background-color:#326690;color:white;min-width:110px;">{% trans 'Confirm' %}</button>
                            <span data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light border" style="float:right;color:#326690;min-width:110px;margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> {% trans 'Cancel' %}</span>              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var form_options = { target: '#modal', success: function(response) {
        <!-- test for form validation status: password changed confirmation message displayed only if form is valid -->
        if(response.data == true){
            <!-- remove grey background -->
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
            $("#password_change_confirm").append('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><span>Your password has been changed successfully.</span></div>');
        }
            
    } };
    $('#password_change').ajaxForm(form_options);

</script>
```

myapp/emplate/myapp/index.html

```
<!-- message for change password in authentification module -->
<div id="password_change_confirm" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;"></div>
```